# How to copy folder content to a existing folder in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up a Docker image with a site I'm building from CI.
The problem I'm having is that I want to copy just the files from the folder to htdocs in the image.
I want to get a structure like this:

- htdocs

  - index.html
  - js
  - bkg.png
  - Build

Rather, I'm getting a copy of my folder inside htdocs

```
root@f0e2001f3a3d:/usr/local/apache2# ls
bin  build  cgi-bin  conf  error  htdocs  icons  include  logs  modules
root@f0e2001f3a3d:/usr/local/apache2# cd htdocs
root@f0e2001f3a3d:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs# ls
WebGL  index.html
root@f0e2001f3a3d:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs# cd WebGL
root@f0e2001f3a3d:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/WebGL# ls
Build  bkg.png  css  index.html  js
```

My dockerfile is:

```
FROM httpd:2.4

COPY build/WebGL /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the files, as opposed to the directory by specifying a `/` on the end of your `COPY` directive. For example:

Source directory

```
$ ls -R
.:
Dockerfile  htdocs

./htdocs:
bkg.png  Build  index.html  js


$ cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine

COPY htdocs/ /tmp/files/

RUN ls -laR /tmp/files
```

Building

```
$ docker build . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
 ---> d4ff818577bc
Step 2/3 : COPY htdocs/ /tmp/files/
 ---> d777a2fbcbb9
Step 3/3 : RUN ls -laR /tmp/files
 ---> Running in fbe75f1353aa
/tmp/files:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Aug  8 23:59 .
drwxrwxrwt    1 root     root          4096 Aug  8 23:59 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root             0 Aug  8 23:12 Build
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root             0 Aug  8 23:12 bkg.png
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root             0 Aug  8 23:12 index.html
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root             0 Aug  8 23:12 js
Removing intermediate container fbe75f1353aa
 ---> 5c2225edb987
Successfully built 5c2225edb987
```